# Tourney drop to flat bar conversion

Tags: road-bike, shifter, conversion, tourney

Is it possible to convert a drop bar road bike with 2x7 Tourney brifters to flat bar using Tourney rapidfire shifters? I believe they only come in 3x7 variant, so is it posible to use that and just limit the front derailleur? Will this even be compatible?

Comment: Welcome to SE - please search the site for relevant answers before asking a new question.  This one comes up periodically.    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54582/ and https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/ are good starts.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick tagging duplicates since compatibility issues are different between groupsets.

Answer (score 5):

You have to consider compatibility between the shifter/brake lever units and:

- Rear derailleur
- Front derailleur
- Brake caliper

Rear derailleur should be fine, Shimano uses the same cable pull ratio for everything 9 speed an below.

Front derailleur is probably OK, although I'm not familiar with Shimano's schemes for front derailleur cable pull ratio.

Brakes can be problematic is there is generally a difference between the leverage ratio in the levers and calipers for 'road' style U-brakes and MTB V-brakes.

Even if you can work out the compatibility issues, the cost of replacing the bars and shifters can be significant compared to the purchase cost of the bike (especially at the Tourney level). Sometimes selling the bike and purchasing one more suitable for your needs is the better way to go.

Comment: For two speeds the front does not matter that much because you can just use limit screws and there's no middle position to worry about.