# Converting flat bar to drop bar on Trek 7500 FX

Tags: hybrid-bike, conversion, drop-bar

I would like to change the flat bars on my Trek 7500 FX hybrid to drop bars but I have been unable to find 3x9 shifters that work with hydraulic disc brakes.
Does such a thing exist?
Are there other factors I need to consider for such a conversion?

Specifications:
Trek 7500 FX with hydraulic disc brakes
3x9 drivetrain
11-34 SRAM PG950 9 speed cassette
26/36/48 chain rings
Shimano Deore LX SGS rear derailleur
Shimano Deore front derailleur

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I convert flat bar to drop bars on a hybrid bike](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/16346/can-i-convert-flat-bar-to-drop-bars-on-a-hybrid-bike)

Comment: Would you accept downtube or stem shifters rather than integrated brifters?   That would separate the functions.  Personally I'd want brifters/STI levers.

Comment: Thanks, I read that post but it doesn’t fully address my situation because I have hydraulic brakes. I can find shifters that will work with mechanical disc brakes but not hydraulic. 
I have considered downtube or even bar end shifters but that is a big sacrifice and I would still have to find hydraulic brake levers.

Comment: If hydraulic brakes are your top requirement, you'll also be limited to 2x transmissions. I'm not aware of 3x brifters with hydraulic brakes. And you won't find any reasonably-priced 2x road/gravel transmission that has the range you have with your current setup.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are no brifters (combined brake levers / shifters) in 9-speed for hydraulic brakes (and couldn't find them either, same as you). The reason for this is that hydraulic for road **rim** brakes were never really a thing, and when the first hydraulic disc brakes appeared, gear count was already at 11.

if you really want to do this, I think the best way would be to change the rear derailleur and the cassette+chain as well to an 11x for which there are hydraulic brifters. Brifters are the expensive part of this refit (at least if you go for the more budget-friendly parts), an RD doesn't add that much, and the cassette+chain are consumables anyway.

If you want to keep your drivetrain, you could in principle buy brifters without using the shifting part and in addition bar-end shift levers, but it would probably be more expensive than replacing the read derailleur.

For left-side only there are also brake levers without shifting functions (ment for 1x drivetrains).

Another thing to consider is geometry: when you get a drop bar, your hand position on the hoods will be more forward than on a straight bar, probably also more forward than on most bar-end configurations.
Hand position on the drops is not comparable at all, of course.
A road bike that fits you well might have a shorter top tube to compensate (This is just an informed guess: you could check on comparison websites like [99spokes](https://99spokes.com/))

I think the best approach is to get another bike (and maybe trade in the old one). If you can get your hands on something used, this might be the same price and less effort. And I think it would be a better bike compared to your converted one.

Comment: Thanks for all those suggestions. I don’t think rider position will be an issue based on analysis of the bike specs but I will certainly double check this.  Meanwhile I think I have found a solution: a Surly Corner Drop bar.  It allows you to use the flat bar shifters and levers. https://surlybikes.com/parts/corner_bar

Comment: Looks interesting, nice find, I asked myself whether a handlebar geometry like this wouldn't be nice. But 63 cm wide seems way too much for me. I'd go for 40-ish >.<

Comment: Out of stock everywhere. Surly doesn’t expect more until September